# How to host a simple website using a domain name I own

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I'm familiar with hosting webapps when I'm doing "the whole shebang" of installing / configuring / setting up Apache/Tomcat/PostreSQL / "coding" the website myself using HTML / JSP / CSS etc. on dedicated servers I'm renting.

But in the above case, I'm "owning" the entire stack: from the Debian GNU/Linux dedicated servers to every single file that is served.

Now I'd like to do something **much** simpler and I must admit I don't know what's involved at all.

I'd like to host a simple website made of only a few static pages (no database, no nothing)  and I'd like it to be accessible from "example.com".

What needs to be technically done to have such a thing?  How is the DNS supposed to be set up?

Note that I do *not* want to host this on one of my dedicated servers.

Comment: Google ubuntu apache configuration 2012 or 2011 and you'll find quite a few tutorials on installing apache2.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not sure what you're after, unless you're just massively overthinking. There's nothing different here from what you already do except you get to skip a bunch of steps. Pick some cheap shared host your friends recommend, pretend someone already did all the Apache/etc setup(because they did), and just ftp your files in.

Comment: @Su': OK I guess FTP (geez, does that still exist?) is great but... My question was also about how to "link" the domain to the FTP hosting company/site I'll be using.

Comment: The hosting company will have instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to point the A-record for your domain to the IP address of your server (or wherever you want to host). If this is a dedicated IP, let it be. If it's shared, you'll need to make sure the server listens in a `VirtualHost` for that exact domain, so it knows to serve the appropriate files.

I know there are a multitude of free web hosts out there, but they usually place ads on your site or limit the amount of bandwidth, etc. Then there are paid hosts. Very reliable in terms of uptime, network speeds, etc. You usually receive a FTP account to upload your files, but a single server may host 1500 sites. Having installed tracking software on many web hosts, I did find that most of them run at 100% CPU 24/7. This isn't really an issue, since the pages are served on-time and you wouldn't notice it unless you were doing calculations and timing tests.

For purely-static content, I don't feel it's worth the time or money investing in a full-out web host, because they offer more than you'd ever need for that type of site.

If you like, you can contact me (click username, homepage, contact page) and I'd be glad to discuss further what your intentions are and find a direction that is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Find a shared hosting service (like godaddy, bluehost, etc.) and sign up there. Free hosting is also available. I searched just now for "free hosting no ads" and found freehostingnoads.com (amazing, right?) which sounds too perfect but might be exactly what you need.

Comment: freehostingnoads.com is just one of those domain squatting holding pages showing a bunch of links/ads?